# How to get time difference between end_time and start_time in attendance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**From the table:**
[image: Attendance_table]

and get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

When I try to calculate the time difference between end and start time and display the result in the same table in another column. *BTW, my table is actually a view.

All of this is done on the MS SQL Server 2012 version. No matter what I try I always get that error. Or some other syntax error. Please, I need a simple code that will just get the difference between the end time and start time and display in the same table in a new column named "Work Hours" or "Duration".

[image: My Code with the error]

Comment: please use plain text  for your code and your sample data so it can be used easily for community, thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The code is too long and stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post with such long codes!!! :(

Comment: That SQL isn't *that* long, and I am confident that if you made it a [mre] it will let you post it.

Comment: @Larnu stackoverflow says my code is too long and doesn't allow me to post.. newbie here!!!

Comment: Which is why I asked you to minimise your problem, @Md.MasumOmarJashim . Images of code will only get your question closed as the user's here aren't going to spend time transcribing it.

Comment: Could you help me understand better... how to minimize that code... please I am a complete newbie when it comes to coding/programming

Comment: Create a [mre].

Comment: Ok. I will need sometime for that.. to better understand what I need to provide. Thanks @Larnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `DATEDIFF`, `DATEADD`, and `CONVERT` can get you what you need.

```
SELECT
    [USER_ID],
    [WORK DATE],
    [START TIME],
    [END TIME],
    CONVERT ( varchar, DATEADD ( ms, DATEDIFF( second, [START TIME], [END TIME] ) * 1000, 0 ), 114 ) AS [WORK HOURS]
FROM ( VALUES 
    ( 1, '01/12/2020', '03:38PM', '07:08PM' ),
    ( 1, '02/12/2020', '6:06AM', NULL ),
    ( 1, '04/11/2020', '11:47AM', NULL ),
    ( 1, '05/11/2020', '01:02PM', '05:10PM' )
) AS LogTime ( [USER_ID], [WORK DATE], [START TIME], [END TIME] );
```

Returns:

```
+---------+------------+------------+----------+--------------+
| USER_ID | WORK DATE  | START TIME | END TIME |  WORK HOURS  |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+--------------+
|       1 | 01/12/2020 | 03:38PM    | 07:08PM  | 03:30:00:000 |
|       1 | 02/12/2020 | 6:06AM     | NULL     | NULL         |
|       1 | 04/11/2020 | 11:47AM    | NULL     | NULL         |
|       1 | 05/11/2020 | 01:02PM    | 05:10PM  | 04:08:00:000 |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+--------------+
```

`DATEDIFF` get the seconds between your starting and ending time.

`DATEADD` factors the seconds to a datetime value.

`CONVERT` returns just the time portion of the factored datetime.

Comment: Thank you!!! Do I have to manually input the data in the ```FROM ( VALUES 
    ( 1, '01/12/2020', '03:38PM', '07:08PM' ),
   ``` part. Is there any way to pull the data from the view table so that it is fully automated?

Comment: No. Replace `FROM ( VALUES...` with `FROM {your table name}`. VALUES is just a place holder for sample data in my example.